# How to solve error "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 8 supplied"

Tags: python, sqlite

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
tableframe="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frames(frame_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nameframe_path TEXT, timestamp TEXT, accelerometro TEXT, giroscopio TEXT, magnetometro TEXT) "
cursor.execute(tableframe)    
for ele in lol:
        for pat in paths:
            if re.search(ele[0],pat):
                dati=('{pat}','{ele[0]}','{ele[1]}','{ele[2]}','{ele[3]}')
                cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO frames(nameframe_path, timestamp, accelerometro, giroscopio, magnetometro) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",(dati))
```

Error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 8 supplied
```

Comment: `executemany()` may need list of lists - list of rows - but you use tuple with strings - only one row - and it treats every string as single row with data `["{", "p", "a", "t", "}"]`. You should use `execute()` instead of `executemany()`. OR you should first create list with all rows and later run `executemany` only once - after `for`-loop

Comment: you should use directly `dati = (pat, ele[0], ele[1], ele[2], ele[3])` without `'{ }'` or you should use `f-string` like `dati = (f'{pat}', f'{ele[0]}', f'{ele[1]}', f'{ele[2]}', f'{ele[3]}')` but first version is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it but problem is because you use `executemany()` in wrong way. It needs list of rows of data but you have only one row in every loop - and it treats every string as row like `["{", "p", "a", "t", "}"]` (which has 5 elements) or `["{", "e", "l", "e", "[", "0", "]", "}"]` (which has 8 elements and you can see this value in error).

In for-loop you need `execute()` instead of `executemany()` (and you don't need `'{ }'` in `dati`

```py
if re.search(ele[0],pat):

    dati = (pat, ele[0] , ele[1], ele[2], ele[3])

    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO frames(nameframe_path, timestamp, accelerometro, giroscopio, magnetometro) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", 
        dati
    )
```

or shorter

```py
if re.search(ele[0],pat):

    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO frames(nameframe_path, timestamp, accelerometro, giroscopio, magnetometro) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", 
        (pat, ele[0] , ele[1], ele[2], ele[3])
    )
```

If you want to use `executemany()` then in `for`-loop you should add data to list of rows and after `for`-loop run `executemany()` with this list.

```py
    # --- before for-loop ---
   
    all_rows = []

    # --- for-loop ---

    for ele in lol:
        for pat in paths:
            if re.search(ele[0],pat):
                dati = (pat, ele[0] , ele[1], ele[2], ele[3])
                all_rows.append(dati) 

    # --- after for-loop ---

    cursor.executemany(
         "INSERT INTO frames(nameframe_path, timestamp, accelerometro, giroscopio, magnetometro) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
         all_rows
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. But I Have another piece of code of another table of the same database. 
`cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pazienti(pazienti_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, namepaziente TEXT)") 
giu=['CT01', CT02', 'CT03'] 
for ele in giu:        
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pazienti(namepaziente) VALUES (?)",(ele))`
It gives me the same problem

Comment: argument has to be tuple so you need comma in `(ele,)` to create tuple with one element. But in this example shuld work `executemany(..., giu)` without `for`-loop if you create nested list `giu=[ ['CT01'], ['CT02'], ['CT03'] ]`.